# Отсортировать Map<Event, List<Data>> по значению List.size

Tags: java, сортировка

я решил вопрос через создание дополнительной мапы и выглядит это жутко.

```
 Map<Event, Integer> typesCountSorted = new HashMap<>();
    Map<Event, List<EventData>> etypesCountSorted;
    etypesCountSorted = events.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(EventData::getType));

 etypesCountSorted.forEach((key, value) -> typesCountSorted.put(key, value.size()));
 typesCountSorted.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Map.Entry.<Event, Integer>comparingByValue().reversed())
        .forEach(entry -> { messageBuilder.append("\n");
          messageBuilder.append(entry.getKey()).append(emojiGen(entry.getKey()));
          messageBuilder.append(": ");
          messageBuilder.append(entry.getValue());
        });
```

думаю что ответ должен быть каким то таким

```
etypesCountSorted.entrySet().stream().sorted(**?????**)
   .forEach(entry -> { messageBuilder.append("\n");
          messageBuilder.append(entry.getKey()).append(emojiGen(entry.getKey()));
          messageBuilder.append(": ");
          messageBuilder.append(entry.getValue());
        });
```

что в сортед подставить?

Comment: Решение  .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt((Entry<Event, List<Data>> entry) -> entry.getValue().size()))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все верно, в sorted нужно поместить следующее лямбда выражение(если нужно по убыванию - поменяйте местами `entry1.getValue().size()` и `entry2.getValue().size()`):

```
(Map.Entry<Event,List<Data>> entry1, Map.Entry<Event,List<Data>> entry2) -> {return entry1.getValue().size() - entry2.getValue().size();}
```

Если уместите в одно выражение, то можно чуть сократить запись:

```
(Map.Entry<String,List<String>> entry1, Map.Entry<String,List<String>> entry2) -> entry1.getValue().size() - entry2.getValue().size()
```

Вот тест:

```
    Map<String, List<String>> m = new HashMap<>();
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>(); 
    arrayList.add("1");
    arrayList.add("2");
    m.put("2", new ArrayList<String>(arrayList));
    arrayList.clear();
    arrayList.add("1");
    arrayList.add("2");
    arrayList.add("3");
    m.put("3", new ArrayList<String>(arrayList));
    arrayList.clear();
    arrayList.add("1");
    m.put("1", new ArrayList<String>(arrayList));

    m.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted((Map.Entry<String,List<String>> entry1, Map.Entry<String,List<String>> entry2) -> {return entry1.getValue().size() - entry2.getValue().size();})
        .forEach((Map.Entry<String,List<String>> entry) -> {System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue().toString());});
```

Вывод:

> 1 [1]
>   2 [1, 2]
>   3 [1, 2, 3]

Comment: большое тебе спасибо, срада разработки поменяла ответ на покороче, но ты очень помог!  Comparator.comparingInt((Entry<Event, List<EventData>> entry) -> entry.getValue().size())